# Disable localization in kendo angular ui

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

We have been supporting localization for our app developed using Angular 7. We have few components which use Kendo Angular UI grid.

We would like to always use English for the Kendo Angular UI components. E.g. date format inside Kendo grid tries to load some locales and throws error "Error: NoLocale: Missing locale info for 'language'".

I want to fix this error by disabling the localization for Kendo Angular UI components. I know we can include locale packages to fix this error but we don't want to increase the package size as of now.

Is there a way to disable the localization for Kendo Angular UI components?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I could set the default locale for Kendo Angular Controls in my app.module.ts's constructor:

```
constructor(public intlService: IntlService) 
{
   (<CldrIntlService>this.intlService).localeId = "en-US";
}
```

So rather than disabling localization, using this way I am overriding the locale set in my app specifically for Kendo components.